# Grub2 countdown slow

Tags: boot, grub2

When booting I have a 3 seconds grub timeout and a countdown to show it:

```
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=false
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=countdown
GRUB_TIMEOUT=3
```

problem is that the 3 seconds countdown countdown takes over 1 minute !
Even worst, I have a feeling it is slowly getting worst :-(
(or may be I am becoming more and more impatient)

version is: `grub-common_2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.12_amd64.deb`
Ubuntu xenial installed on a Macbook

Found a few posts reporting the same problem on the net, but no solution :-(

Anybody has an idea what could be the problem (and the solution)?

Comment: Did you run `sudo update-grub`?

Comment: @Pilot6: I hadn't tried, but I just did it and no improvement: the 3 seconds countdown takes over 1 minute

Comment: @DavidFoerster: I know how to setup the grub timeout, that's not the problem, but rather how to make this timeout behave as expected (i.e. TIMEOUT=3 should last 3 seconds)

Comment: Could you please upload `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` to a pastie service (e. g. https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and [edit] your question to add a link to it? Thanks.

Comment: Could you measure your times with a clock of some sort?

Comment: Hi, waltinator. I did, when Isay over a minute in the question, it is actually 1minute and 3 seconds last time I measured.

Comment: @NicolasAnquetil Does every boot take so long? I had a similar problem with my Thinkpad T470, once in a while it downlocks and is terribly slow (that includes UEFI and OS startup).

Comment: Hi all, thanks for trying to help me. Sorry it took so long to answer you all.I ended up erasing everything and reinstalling from scratch :-(

Answer (score 3):

To apply your setting in `/etc/default/grub` you need to run

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: Sorry, did not work

Answer (score 0):

Delete your 4 lines and paste:

```
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT="0"
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET="true"
GRUB_TIMEOUT="3"
```

and then run `sudo update-grub`

Answer (score -1):

For the record, the following [post](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1668105) describes (more accurately) the same problem I had.
It also proposes a solution (post #6):
"1. Boot the Apple computer to grub, takes about 2 minutes
2. Press a key, then edit your boot configuration to include the kernel command line parameter break, takes about 2 minutes
3. At the initramfs prompt usb works fine. Enter command reboot
4. This initiates a graceful shutdown of Linux, and the Apple computer can now be booted with usb3 operating normally"

Another post (#28) also proposes:
"I updated to kernel 4.12 and the kernel recover usb failures on boot"

None of these worked for me :-(

Comment: Please include a relevant quote from that link, about the problem, and the solution. Without that, your answer is pretty much a link-only answer (at risk to be deleted via moderation).